# How and when does Class T change from Integer to String rather than showing error/exception

Tags: java, generics, incompatibletypeerror

What i have done is to just get to know how Generics works in Java.
I have written the following code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{  
        Foo o = new Foo<Integer>(new Integer(5));
        o.fun();
    }
}       

class Foo<T> {

    private T t;

    public Foo(T t) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{
       System.out.println("1. T is "+t.getClass());
       this.t = (T)"test";
       System.out.println("2. T is "+t.getClass());
   }

   void fun(){
       System.out.println("3. T is "+t.getClass()+" t = "+t);
   }
}
```

And output is

```
1. T is class java.lang.Integer
2. T is Still class java.lang.Integer
3. T is class java.lang.String t = test
```

**My question is Why this is changing Class from Integer to String and not showing error/exception.**

And second thing is that when I write `t = 9;` in `function fun()`, it shows:

```
incompatible types
required: T
found:    java.lang.Integer
```

**How do generic classes work and how are they used?**

*Your response will be greatly appreciated!!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared a generic with [no upper bound](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html). Replacement for an unbounded generic
is `Object` itself

This means, when the class file gets generated your `Foo<T>` class looks something like this

```
class Foo {

    private Object t;

    public Foo(Object  t) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{
       System.out.println("1. T is "+t.getClass());
       this.t = (Object)"test";
       System.out.println("2. T is "+t.getClass());
   }

   void fun(){
       System.out.println("3. T is "+t.getClass()+" t = "+t);
   }
}
```

This is due to the fact that, generics are only there to ensure **compile time type safety** . In run-time they are **erased**

Considering this

```
this.t = (Object)"test";
```

is a valid statement, because `Object` is super class of all the classes and `this.t` then on becomes a `String`

The reason for `2. T is Still class java.lang.Integer` ,

- here `t` is a *parameter to the constructor* and the parameter still points to `Integer` (not overwritten)
- and the parameter takes precedence over `this.t`

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem:

```
private T t;
```

t is a class variable here.

```
       System.out.println("1. T is "+t.getClass());
       this.t = (T)"test";
       System.out.println("2. T is "+t.getClass());
```

In above code in your sysout, the variable you are printing is 't' which is passed to method, not your class varible 't' declared above (this.t)

Class variable 't' got updated to 'String' Type, which gets printed in your "fun()" method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your declaration `Foo o = new Foo<Integer>(new Integer(5));` should be `Foo<Integer> o = new Foo<Integer>(new Integer(5));` (or if you're using Java 7 and above the diamond operator) like this `Foo<Integer> o = new Foo<>(5));`. The original `fun()` gets called on the base Foo (equivalend to `Foo<Object>` after type erasure). Which is to say it works like this

```
void fun() {
  Object o = t;
  System.out.println("3. T is " + o.getClass()
      + " t = " + t);
}
```

Also your constructor should be

```
this.t = (T) t;
```

And NOT this

```
this.t = (T)"test"; // Which is why you're getting a String!
```

Answer (score 0):

' this.t = (T)"test";' this is wrong. you cant change type of class. firstly defined. in class T must be Integer because firstly you gave type as Integer [generics example link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)

when you see ,replace all 'T' to 'Integer'. good hacking